# How to program Kinesis Triple Foot Pedals for Advantage Keyboards to simulate mouse clicks? (macOS)

Tags: macos, keyboard, kinesis-advantage

How can I program my Kinesis Triple Foot Pedals for Advantage Keyboards to simulate mouse clicks, so that stepping on the left pedal will simulate a single left mouse click, stepping on the middle pedal will simulate a double left mouse click, and stepping on the right pedal will simulate a right mouse click?

---

**Operating system**: macOS Sierra Version 10.12.4
**Keyboard**: Kinesis Advantage Keyboard - USB Contoured keyboard (Mac/PC Switchable) - KB500USB
**Foot Pedals**: Kinesis - Foot Pedals for Advantage Keyboards - Triple Pedal - FS007TAF

Comment: I've never ever tried it, so might need a bit of experimentation, but have you tried System Prefs > Accessibility > Switch Control ?